# Is MANOVA the correct analysis for this case?

Tags: r, manova

During an experiment I presented participants with some sound stimuli and I asked them to modify two parameters of the sound (Centroid and Sound_Level_Peak) to reach a given experimental goal. The sounds represented hand interactions with different kinds of materials by means of different kinds of objects, and where created thanks to a parametric synthesizer.

The initial sounds (preset sounds) had a value for those two parameters. What I am interested in is whether participants' modifications of the two parameters of the sound stimuli resulted in values actually different from the initial values of the parameters of the preset sounds.

In more details, the experiment involved 19 subjects, who where subjected to 12 kinds of stimuli, each based on 3 presets of centroid and peak level (so in total there where 36 stimuli). Each stimulus was repeated twice for a total of 72 trials per subject. Accordingly, the number of presets was 72.

To give an idea, some rows of my data set are the following:

```
> head(scrd) 
Stimulus_Type   Centroid        Sound_Level_Peak    Preset
Stimulus_A      1960.2          -20.963             no
Stimulus_A      5317.2          -42.741             no
.....
Stimulus_B      11256.0          -16.480            no
Stimulus_B      9560.3          -19.682             no
.....
.....
Stimulus_A      1900.2          -18.63             yes
Stimulus_A      5617.6          -44.41             yes
Stimulus_B      12056.0          -17.80            yes
Stimulus_B      8960.5          -21.82             yes
```

This is the analysis I performed:

```
> fit <- manova(cbind(Centroid,Sound_Level_Peak)~ Stimulus_Type*Preset, data=scrd)
> summary(fit, test="Pillai")
                       Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df  Pr(>F)    
Stimulus_Type          11 0.91888  106.629     22   2760 < 2e-16 ***
Preset                  1 0.00343    2.371      2   1379 0.09378 .  
Stimulus_Type:Preset   11 0.01155    0.729     22   2760 0.81348    
Residuals            1380                                           
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
>
```

These results should then say that for each stimulus type there is no difference between the patterns of the two parameters in the preset and modified conditions.

Can anyone please tell me if this analysis is correct or suggest how to perform in R an alternative analysis?

Comment: Can you please throw in some context on what you are measuring to make it more fun?

Comment: @AntoniParellada I have added the following sentence, "The sounds represented hand interactions with different kinds of materials by means of different kinds of objects, and where created thanks to a parametric synthesizer." Is it enough?